# CMake Target_Link_Libraries fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I know this topic already has been discussed more than once, but I do not understand what is going wrong. I looked up several websites but none of the provided approaches worked for me.

I want to create a VS solution with CMake which consists of 10 projects. **Each project** has to link `myLibrary.lib`.

```
#CMakeLists.txt:

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Project_Example) 

SET(SRC_DIR_PATH C++)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "inc" )                          # OK, tested and works
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)     # OK, tested and works
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${BINNAME} ${SRCS})                    # ?No idea?
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${BINNAME} myLibrary.lib)       # fails

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_01 )
IF( TRUE )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_02 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_03 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_04 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_05 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_06 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_07 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_08 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_09 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_10 )
ENDIF()
```

Each Project has its own `CMakeLists.txt` which looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

MESSAGE( STATUS "## ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ##" )

IF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows" )
  ### Windows ###
  SET( LIB_PROJECT myLibrary )
  SET( LIB_SYSTEM  )
ELSEIF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux" )
  ### Linux ###
  SET( LIB_PROJECT myLibrary dl )
  SET( LIB_SYSTEM /usr/local/lib )
ENDIF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows" )


SET( SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT Project_01 )
SET( PROJECT_EXAMPLE ${SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT} )

SET( SOURCE_FILES
  ${SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT}.cpp
)


FOREACH( Librarys ${LIB_PROJECT} )
  MESSAGE("#### Librarys:${Librarys} next will find ...")
  SET( SHAREDLIB ${SHAREDLIB}-NOTFOUND )
  FIND_LIBRARY ( SHAREDLIB
    NAMES ${Librarys}
    PATHS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib ${LIB_SYSTEM}
    )
  MESSAGE("#### SHAREDLIB:${SHAREDLIB}")
  IF( SHAREDLIB )
    SET( LIBS_ALL ${LIBS_ALL} ${SHAREDLIB} )
    SET( SHAREDLIB ${SHAREDLIB}-NOTFOUND )
  ENDIF()
  MESSAGE("#### ${LIBRARY} found LIBS_ALL${LIBS_ALL}")
ENDFOREACH( Librarys )


ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_EXAMPLE} ${SOURCE_FILES} ) 

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_EXAMPLE} ${LIBS_ALL})
```

The CMakeLists from these projects are used since long time and therefore considered to be OK. The Problem occured when integrating all projects to one CMake solution.

The error I'm getting is: `"SHAREDLIB:SHAREDLIB-NOTFOUND"

[image: cmake error, occurs for each project]`

There's also a warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt: (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES): 
Cannot specify link libraries for target "MyLibrary.lib" which is not build by this project.

CMake does not support this but it is used to work accidentally ans is being allowed for compatibility.

Policy CMP0016 is not set: target_link_libraries() reports error if only argument is not a target. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0016" for policy details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

So again, I want to add this library to any project in this solution.

My folders are something like:

```
C++\
     inc\    -> header files
     lib\    -> libraries
     src\    -> sources with 10 different folders of c++ files
```

CMake command is:

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" --build .. -DWIN_64:BOOL=OFF`

I'm using CMake 2.8 and VS 2010.

Comment: Looks like a typo - `$(BINNAME)` should be `${BINNAME}`?

Comment: @Fraser You're right, thx. But now it's another error: `LIB-NOTFOUND`

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: @arrowdodger `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" --build .. -DWIN_64:BOOL=OFF`

Comment: @fiscblog Where _in your CMakeLists.txt_ are you getting this error? The code you posted does not even have a variable `SHAREDLIB`. Could you please put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us? Otherwise this will turn into a guessing game.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Sorry, wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Updated my question to a maximum level of detail I can possibly provide.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was the following:

```
#CMakeLists.txt global:

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Project_Example) 

SET(SRC_DIR_PATH C++)


ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_01 )
IF( TRUE )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_02 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_03 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_04 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_05 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_06 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_07 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_08 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_09 )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src/Project_10 )
ENDIF()
```

As you can see, I removed both Include and Link instructions from the golbal CMakeLists. Instead I put them into the appropriate CMakeLists file:

```
#CMakeLists.txt local (for each project):   

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)        

MESSAGE( STATUS "## ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ##" )    

SET(CMAKE_PROJECTNAME Project_01)    
SET(PROJECT_BINARY_DIR ../..)    

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/inc" )    


IF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows" )     
   ### Windows ###      
   SET( LIB_PROJECT MyLibrary )      
   SET( LIB_SYSTEM  )    
ELSEIF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux" )      
   ### Linux ###
  SET( LIB_PROJECT MyLibrary dl )      
   SET( LIB_SYSTEM /usr/local/lib/ )    
ENDIF ( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows" )

SET( SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT Project_01 )    
SET( PROJECT_EXAMPLE ${SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT} )    
SET( SOURCE_FILES
  ${SOURCE_WITHOUT_EXT}.cpp
)

FOREACH( Librarys ${LIB_PROJECT} )      
   MESSAGE("#### Librarys:${Librarys} next will find ...")      
   SET( SHAREDLIB ${SHAREDLIB}-NOTFOUND )      
   FIND_LIBRARY ( SHAREDLIB
    NAMES ${Librarys}
    PATHS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib ${LIB_SYSTEM}
    )

   MESSAGE("#### SHAREDLIB:${SHAREDLIB}")      
   IF( SHAREDLIB )        
      SET( LIBS_ALL ${LIBS_ALL} ${SHAREDLIB} )        
      SET( SHAREDLIB ${SHAREDLIB}-NOTFOUND )      
      ENDIF()
  MESSAGE("#### ${LIBRARY} found LIBS_ALL${LIBS_ALL}")    
ENDFOREACH( Librarys )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_EXAMPLE} ${SOURCE_FILES} ) 

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_EXAMPLE} ${LIBS_ALL})
```

Although this works now, I'm still asking myself what if I had not 10 but 100 projects? This would be really pain in the ass to modify each CMakeLists individually.